# False positive on optional in Swift5.4

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift5

I have a Dictionary extension which has worked perfectly up until the release of Xcode 12.5 with Swift 5.4.
The problem is that in Swift5.4 there seems to have been a change which makes an optional optional return as a false positive. In ways it does make sense however now my extension fails.

Consider the following example code:

```swift
let dictionary: [String: Any] = ["foo": "bar"]

if let foo = dictionary["foo"] as? String? {
    debugPrint("Foo exists")
}

if let bar = dictionary["bar"] as? String? {
    debugPrint("bar exists")
}
```

In pre Swift 5.4 this would result in the following:

```
"Foo exists"
```

However now in Swift 5.4 I get the following result:

```
"Foo exists"
"bar exists"
```

This is due to that even though the dictionary is defined as `[String: Any]`, an `String?` conforms to type `Any` and thus `nil` conforms to `any` and so the if case would trigger since nil is any.

For me this brings an issue with a require function I'm using, which triggers if the generic type is set to optional. My extension:

```swift
enum DictionaryExtractionError: Error {
    case missingProperty(String), casting(String)
}

extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
    func require<T>(_ name: String) throws -> T {
        if let prop = self[name] as? T, (prop as Any?) != nil {
            return prop
        }
        throw self[name] == nil ? DictionaryExtractionError.missingProperty(name) : DictionaryExtractionError.casting(name)
    }

    func require<T>(_ name: String, fallback: T) -> T {
        do {
            return try require(name) ?? fallback
        } catch {
            return fallback
        }
    }
}

let dictionary: [String: Any] = ["fooBar": "barFoo"]
let valid: String = dictionary.require("fooBar", fallback: "no Foobar")
let validMissing: String = dictionary.require("doesntExist", fallback: "no Foobar")
let inValidMissing: String? = dictionary.require("doesntExist", fallback: "no Foobar")

debugPrint(valid) // Should return: "barFoo"
debugPrint(validMissing) // Should return: "no Foobar"
debugPrint(inValidMissing) // Should return: Optional("no Foobar") <<<<<< This one is wrong
```

My question: Is there some way to check if `T` is of optional type? If so I can adapt my code to check where generic type is optional, make sure `prop` is not nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example code prints `"bar exists"` in Xcode 12.4 also.

Anyway, try this implementation of `require` instead:

```
func require<T>(_ name: String) throws -> T {
    guard let index = self.index(forKey: name) else {
        throw DictionaryExtractionError.missingProperty(name)
    }
    guard let t = self[index].value as? T else {
        throw DictionaryExtractionError.casting(name)
    }
    return t
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got so stuck in my if let I forgot the index approach. Will try it out shortly but by the looks of it, it looks great. Thought I had pinned it down to the small example, either way the extension didn’t work on 5.4 but does on 5.3 (although I modified it a little in the example above). Thanks again!

Comment: Ended up changing it to a `guard let prop = self[name] else { … } guard let castedProp = prop as? T else { … }`. This due to that I don’t have use for the index anyways and it makes it a little clearer to read.